# Use flutter_blue to determine if your phone is paired to a device

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to be able to display to my app user if I am paired to a particular BLE device or not. I am using flutter_blue. Is there a way I can do this without having to write platform specific code?

Currently, all of the solutions I see involve using flutter_blue_serial. However, upon reading the plugins description it appears to not support BLE communications.

Answer (score -1):

No there is no such way. You'll be needing to personally access the native code as plugins at pub.dev are not allowed to change your native Android/iOS code.

Comment: I noticed there is a variable print out called status when the device's state changes in flutter_blue when connecting to a non-paired device. Would it be possible to use this value to determine if the device is paired? I haven't found a way to access that particular value.